# How can I upload data to db and open Bootstrap Modal popup from a submit?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that when the submit is click it will currently upload data to my db and then unhide a div below which shows the section to upload files. This works well but is filling a lot of space when I have a number of forms like this on one page. I am looking at having the upload section on a Bootstrap Modal.

No when I have the 2 different sections working seperately each does as I want them to. The problem is when I want them to work from the one Submit button. How can I get the Boostrap Modal to open and also send the Form data to the db?

My form

```
<form name="myform">
    <!-- all my form detail is here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-circle btn-info" id="conflandreg" name="conflandreg">Click to confirm details <span class="icon-check"></span></button>
</form>
```

The jQuery to use when the Submit is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#landregform').on('submit',function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'includes/leadgen/lg_lruploads.php',
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        type:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('showhidelr').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ownership').style.display = 'block';
        },
        error:function(data){
            $(".alert-danger'").show().fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

If I add in this to the Submit button `data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#lrupload" data-toggle="modal"` then the Bootstrap Modal will load, but the form doesnt submit.

How can I get the form to Submit and open the Bootstrap Modal from the same Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and show a modal via js instead of via data attributes, simply change your success callback like so:

```
success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#lrupload').modal('show');
},
```

Answer (score 1):

How about rather than listen to on 'submit' you listen for on click?

Then you can control it more easily. My guess is that as you are waiting for submit it leaves before you can do anything else.

So:

```
$('#landregform').on('click',function(e) {
openDialog();
submitAction();
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```